# Clicking favorites bar links in IE8 sometimes causes file download dialog?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Occasionally when I click a link in my Favorites Bar IE8 will open a file download prompt for the shortcut itself (.url file).

Very annoying.

Has anyone else experienced this? I swear I encounter this at least once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found someone else with same [problem](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34433544/file-download-prompt-when.aspx). I can reproduce this by clickng "New Tab" then immediately clicking a favorites link.

A "solution" to this is to just **Ctrl+click** the favorites bar links to open them in a new tab.

Seems kinda stupid to click "New Tab" first only to click a favorites bar link thereafter. /facepalm

Answer (score 2):

could you be catching a modifier key on your keyboard, or have a sticky key (an actual physical sticky key, or one emulated by the accessibility options)?

There is a combination (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click IIRC) that explicitly means "download the file pointed to by this link" not "go to this link".

Answer (score 0):

If a particular favorite got created with a URL to a .url file (that is, a shortcut) then IE will see that as you trying to download a .url file which it knows to flag as suspicious behavior.  Check the address of the shortcuts in question (right-click on it, get properties, look at the URL box) and check to see if this is the case.

This can happen a couple of different ways.  Dragging a Favorite that someone sends you via email or that you've created on your desktop are the most frequent ways I've seen.

Comment: No, they're regular URL shortcuts. The URL is pointing the real web address. They're not shortcuts 'to' .url files.